# Refreshing only part of the page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have some tabs/lists:

```
<div id="tabs">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Recs", "Recs", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Software", "Software", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
             </div>
```

On these lists, I have some JQuery slide effects, so the div slides in when a user enters the site. But they also slide in everytime the page is reloaded, like when a user clicks on one of the tabs. This can get annoying in the long run, it's only cool when you enter the site. So I want to make it so that a specific area of the page is reloaded (And not the lists). I found out that I can use AJAX load(...) for this, and that I should use a Partial View. So I have a Partial View that looks like this:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.PageRefreshModel

<div id="retrievedContentDiv">
   <h2>Some content</h2>
</div>
```

And the JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#topMenuContentDiv li").click(function () {
        $("#retrievedContentDiv").load("/PageRefresh/RefreshPage", { type: 'POST' });
    });

});
```

And the part of the _Layout.cshtml that renders the Partial View contains this:

```
    @RenderBody()
    <div>
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_RefreshedHandler");}
    </div>
```

where _RefreshedHandler is the Partial View.
So far, the Controller for the Partial View looks like this:

```
public ActionResult RefreshPage()
        {
            return PartialView("_RefreshedHandler");
        }
```

I am totally lost in where to go from here. Eventually the partial view will return the content that belongs to the tab/view that was clicked. But the issue right now is how I can make it so that the tab/list section is not reloaded on a click.

The solution with AJAX is what I have been able to find with long time on searching the internet. If anyone knows a better solution, or if asp.net mvc has it's own embedded way for dealing with this, please share. Also you are welcome to recommend better solutions or point out problems with my solution so far

Answer (score 1):

Not going into your code, but there are currently two concepts of building webistes:

- The classic page by page approch, where each click loads a completly new page
- The Single Page Application (SPA) approch, where you load the site once and then only the missing data via an REST API

Your question looks like an SPA, you load the site and then want to manipulate diffent parts without reloading other parts.

The best framework for building such applications currently is [angular.js](https://angularjs.org/). There are nice toturals on the page, and there are a lot of examples how to "integrate" it into ASP.Net-MVC.

Other similar frameworks are

- knockoutjs
- Backbone.js

but in my opinion, angularjs is the most advanced.